# Alternate for CustomErrors Mode = "RemoteOnly" in Asp.NetCore web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-core, web-config

I have an AspNet Core web application, in which I want to show custom errors only when someone is accessing the application remotely. In case this application is being accessed locally ,i want to keep the detailed error page for the developer. In .netFramework 4.x and earlier, we were able to specify this in web.config customErrors property with mode=RemoteOnly. I am aware about the fact that we can make user of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to turn on custom error or developer exception page in aspnetcore. But what I am looking for is -to have similar functionality for CustomErrors mode = RemoteOnly in AspNetCore.

Comment: The problem is that when the error handling is being configured in `Startup`, there is no active request, and as such, there's no way to determine whether it's "remote" or not. You'd likely need to create some sort of custom middleware for this, but that's far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. You'll need to do your own research and attempt a solution on your own first.

Comment: That's right. We cant have a check like Request.IsLocal = true in startup.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, I don't believe there is an straight forward replacement for CustomErrors key in the Web.config.  However, there are a few more methods available on the IHostingEnvironment interface that may be of use for you depending on what you're trying to implement.  For example you could check multiple environments:

```
if (env.IsProduction() || env.IsStaging() || env.IsEnvironment("Staging_2"))
{
    // Handle the custom errors here
}
```

There is decent documentation on different ways to implement environment specific features [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Can you please throw some more light on how checking for multiple environments can suffice for checking if the request has been made locally or remotely? I just want to make sure that i am not missing anything regarding my understanding for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  variable.

Comment: Presumably you know which environments (Staging, Production, etc) are running on a remote client and which are expected to run locally (development).  Based on those environments you can handle exceptions as necessary.

Comment: This answer doesn't help at all. The OP wants something similar to RemoteOnly. With that setting, the same site in the same environment will return error pages to remote clients, but developer exception pages over localhost. As such, this can't be done via environments because it's always the same environment regardless of the source of the request.

Comment: No. The environment is determined at app startup via the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. That does not change per request, nor based on where that request is coming from. If it's set as `Production` then it's *always* `Production`, regardless of whether it's coming over localhost or not.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I think you lost me at _"this can't be done via environments because it's always the same environment regardless of the source of the request"_.  Wouldn't a request for `https://localhost/...` be determined as a Development environment, where as a request for `https://prodDomain/...` be determined as a Production environment? (As long as the environment is configured on the hosts)

Comment: The point is that it's the *same* host. In one request, it's coming remote over something like `http://sample.com` and in another it's being run locally on the server via `http://locahost`. Same server, same site, same host, same environment.

Comment: I guess maybe I misconstrued the OP's initial question.  When I read "_In case this application is being accessed locally_", I saw it as requesting the application on a local machine (on a different server from where the application is actually deployed). Sorry for the confusion.