# Can I show detailed (debug) error messages to a few sources in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, iis, custom-errors

I have a ASP.Net Core Application that is working fine in development but it is failing when deployed at the target.

I believe I know what the error is, however, I'm finding it very difficult to debug as it doesn't appear to be logging anywhere, and it is just displaying the default error:

"Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application."

Without switching the whole environment to debug mode, is there a way to just display detailed errors to a few source IP addresses?

I'm ideally looking for a modern equivalent of `customErrors="RemoteOnly"` that also works for a few predefined IPs, but, if I have to access from the local machine, I'm fine with that.

Comment: There's no equivalent for ASP.NET Core. Increased and better logging is your best bet, but running the app from the command line on the server does in a pinch. Open a command prompt to your site directory and run `dotnet MyApp.dll`. This should start up the app on `localhost:5000`, which you can then browse to on your server. Recreate the steps to cause the exception, and then go look at the console window. The exception, along with full stack trace, will be there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question asked here [Alternate for CustomErrors Mode = "RemoteOnly" in Asp.NetCore web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689682/alternate-for-customerrors-mode-remoteonly-in-asp-netcore-web-applications)

Basically, I'm not aware of an equivalent of `customErrors="RemoteOnly"` in Asp.net Core, but you can use its [logging API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) along with a 3rd party provider like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) to easily log to a number of [different sources](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks). For remote, I'd log to file or Application Insights. Hope this helps somewhat!